# Identify this Solitaire with 4 piles of 4 cards

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire

I am looking for a Solitaire game, the rules are:

- **Setup**: deal 4 piles of 4 cards. Only the top card is face up. Then you flip over the top card in your hand. That becomes the starter card for the first row.
- **Play**: you can play any card from that suit on the row. You may not start another row until you get a starter card from another suit. Once two or more rows are started you can only play a card on a row if the same card in a different suit is on the row above it.
- If you take a card from one of the four piles, you turn over the next card.

You win the game when all of the cards have been played.

Comment: maybe you can find your game in this index of ~540 solitaire games:  https://www.bvssolitaire.com/solitaire-game-list.htm

Comment: I'm not sure what the best cite for it is, but I believe this game is called Osmosis.